# Identificar se o teclado do celular está aberto

Tags: javascript, html

Sei que é possível identificar quando a pessoa clica num elemento determinado da tela pela primeira vez, mas se fosse melhorar isso.

Como poderia identificar se o teclado do celular está aberto quando alguém clicar num campo de texto através do navegador do celular, por exemplo?

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso através de javascript?

```
<script>
function seiQueAbriuOTeclado() {
  //aqui sabemos que ele abriu, mas por dedução, porque sabemos que ele clicou...
}
</script>
<form>
   <input onclick="seiQueAbriuOTeclado()">
</form>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de acessar via webview algum plugin que faça essa relação com cordova, como o ionic framework faz.

[Dúvidas similares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241492/how-to-listen-for-keyboard-open-close-in-javascript-sencha)

[Aqui um exemplo básico](http://jsfiddle.net/qu1ssabq/3/)

Comment: Pelo que entendo não é possível verificar se o teclado estar aberto sem ser por dedução. O que você pode fazer é um listener para o evento de focus em elementos que abre o teclado e um listener para o evento de blur em elementos que o teclado fecha para assim ter um controle.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia verificar se a pessoa está em um [Dispositivo movel](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/):

```
    function verificacao() { var check = false; //wrapper no check
        (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera)
        return check;
    }
```

E se o a pessoa estiver em um dispositivo mobile e o OnFocus for acionado você vai saber que o teclado apareceu.

Comment: Digamos que meu sistema já identifique que estou em um mobile, em vez de fazer a checagem de onclick eu checasse o foco no campo, `onFocus="abriuTeclado()"`,  como saber se o teclado foi fechado mesmo se perder o foco no campo?

Comment: Até porque é possível fechar o teclado se a pessoa apertar o botão voltar do celular.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o perguntando:

> Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de acessar via webview algum plugin que faça essa relação com cordova

Sim, Ionic é cordova, o núcleo dele pelo menos, por exemplo o plugin usado pelo Ionic é o https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard, que é baseado no https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard, para instalar basta usar o comando

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

Você pode checar se esta visivel com:

```
if (cordova.plugins.Keyboard.isVisible) {
    ...
}
```

Ou usar o evento:

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', function () {
    // dispara quando o teclado se torna visivel
});
```

Via JavaScript puro não tem recurso para isso, o evento `focus` não vai checar se o teclado é visivel, vai checar se o campo esta focado, o teclado estando visivel em campo focado é mera "conveniência"